# Ruby on Rails 4 - Authentication with Linkedin and OmniAuth

Tags: oauth-2.0, linkedin-api, omniauth

I am trying to setup LinkedIn authentication with my Rails app. It uses devise and omniauth (with omniauth-linkedin-oauth2).

I need some help because the information is not coming correctly, such as the user's public URL. Someone could indicate the correct process, but not what is in their documentation, as I have tried and it does not work. Thankful.

Answer (score 0):

The docs say that you need to add `r_basicprofile` to your request. You can do that through the devise initializer

```
config.omniauth :omniauth-linkedin-oauth2, CLIENT_KEY, CLIENT_SECRET, scope: r_basicprofile
```

With that, you should have access to the `public-profile-url` key in the auth hash.

[LinkedIn Docs](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/fields/basic-profile)

Comment: **with out a special linkedin authorize, you have this error:** ERROR -- omniauth: (linkedin) Authentication failure! invalid_credentials: OAuth2::Error, : 
{"serviceErrorCode":100,"message":"Not enough permissions to access: GET /me","status":403}